# Navigation Component , add or replace fragments or other things like hide show fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

how can we specify replace or add fragment in Navigation component?

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_categoriesFragment)
```

Comment: Try this: `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(your_fragment_id)` instead of your action ID.

Comment: I update my question

Comment: It's done automatically, You don't have to add or replace, you just have to navigate using their Ids and instead of FrameLayout, you have NavHostFragment in your activity

Comment: I tried it didn't work

Comment: Okay what is the actual requirement of yours?

Comment: the new fragment add, and when back button clicked previews fragment load(new instance of first fragment load - reiniialize)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183184/discussion-between-mohammad-hadi-and-umang-ssurman).

Comment: The navigation component using replace method, you cannot change it.

Comment: how we can stop reload fragment after back press?

Comment: @charisharma you can't do that currently navigation component using replace method.

Answer (score 2):

If you just use `findNavController().navigate(R.id.someDestinationId)` this kind of equals to `fragmentManager.add` but if you want the replace behavior and you don't want the user be able to press back and reload the previous activity you should do like this:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.homeFragment, null, NavOptions.Builder()
                .setPopUpTo(R.id.loginFragment, true)
                .build())
```

In this case I'm inside **LoginFragment** and I want to navigate to **HomeFragment** and I also would like to replace current fragment so the user won't be able to press back and load the **LoginFragment** again

Comment: May I know the source of this answer?? as I want to explore a bit more on it

Comment: navigate does replace not add

Answer (score 2):

Jetpack Navigation Component supports replacing fragments as of now.

**There is no support for adding fragments**.

Workaround to retain api data in fragment when back button is pressed is to either save the data (Fragment viewstate) in a ViewModel and make a check in onViewCreated() or to use Full Screen DialogFragments. For dialog fragment check this https://gist.github.com/utkukutlu/bd2e37253e7184179d923321e3ea72c1